# MySQL trigger will not execute will NULL value for one field

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm having issues with a trigger not running when I have missing field data.

When I create a new record I would like the filled fields to be concatenated and the empty fields to remain blank.

For example in my form it is not always required to have an email address however if I do not enter something in for the email address the trigger does not run and the data field I do need doesn't get concatenated. My current work round is to add a default value to the email field but I would rather it be blank and for the the trigger to run even when some fields are empty. In this case it is just the email address which will be blank from time to time.

```
BEGIN
  SET NEW.data = CONCAT(NEW.green, ',', NEW.language, ',', NEW.map, ',', NEW.welcome, ',', NEW.label, ',', NEW.path, ',', NEW.email);
END
```

Any advise is gratefully received.

Comment: So you would like to detect if the email field is empty, if it is set the `data` field to a concatenation of everything **but** the email field and if the email field contains something `data` should contain all the concatenated fields?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps the simple work round is to just have a space as the default value? Not visible to users but allows the trigger to run. Not the best technical answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand 100% of your question so here is my answer based on my understanding of your question:

```
BEGIN
  SET NEW.data = IF( NEW.email IS NULL OR NEW.email = '',
                    CONCAT(NEW.green, ',', NEW.language, ',', NEW.map, ',', NEW.welcome, ',', NEW.label, ',', NEW.path),
                    CONCAT(NEW.green, ',', NEW.language, ',', NEW.map, ',', NEW.welcome, ',', NEW.label, ',', NEW.path, ',', NEW.email)
                    );
END
```

Note that this is if `email` is empty more than 50% of the time. If the reverse is true, you should change the condition to `NEW.email IS NOT NULL AND NEW.email != ''` and reverse the `CONCAT`s for optimal execution.

Comment: Ahh OK just run the trigger twice. Not sure we nee the if statement as I would like it to run every time a record in inserted regardless of if the email is blank or not. Is that what the IF statement means? Thanks for your help

Comment: The condition in the `IF` statement will be checked with every insertion, yes, but that kind of simple validation is extremely fast. Only the appropriate `CONCAT` will be executed (e.g. with or without email) though.